# In MS Access, is it possible to execute multiple queries?

Tags: database, jet

I'm trying to execute a statement like:

`UPDATE table1 SET name="Joe" WHERE id='1'; UPDATE table2 SET name="Bob" WHERE id='2'`

But, when executing the query, I get:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'
>
> Characters found after end of SQL statement.

It works when I execute the statements separately, though.

So I'm guessing there's absolutely no way to execute multiple queries in a single SQL statement when using Microsoft Access/JET database engine?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838593/how-do-i-execute-multiple-sql-statements-in-access-query-editor

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way to do this except through VBA or such like, when the statements can be Executed seperately, but as a single procedure.

Comment: I'm basically trying to do (in ASP) conn.Execute("query1; query2; query3"), but the only possible way I can do this is conn.Execute("query1"), conn.Execute("query2"), conn.Execute("query3")?

Comment: Yes, one by one is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way is [Create Stored a Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845861.aspx) and just execute it in your code. with [exec](http://www.ehow.com/how_7350298_call-using-ms-access-vba.html) command.

Comment: have u looked into this @Kamil ?
http://www.ehow.com/how_7350298_call-using-ms-access-vba.html

Comment: I didn't saw that article, thanks.

BTW after you changed whole answer my comment is obsolete ;) Next time delete wrong post and write new one, because you can't edit others comments related with previous version of post.

Comment: hey, Thanks a lot, I'm a newbie in Stackoverflow :D will do