# calling a query from a report textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a report based on a number of different queries.  Most of the queries use the value of a row's customerID textbox as a key to extract specific data from other fields.

Here is what I have for the Control Source property of one of the textboxes:

```
=DLookUp([Level],[qryLevel],[Me].[customerID])
```

Here is the SQL for qryLevel:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Level, myDate FROM sometable WHERE custID=Me.customerID ORDER BY myDate DESC
```

qryLevel works when tested independently, but the DLookUp function does not seem to be working properly because Access gives a dialog box asking for each parameter and then outputs #NAME? in the textbox when no values are input into the dialog boxes.

How can I get each of these textboxes to output its own result from a separate query?

Answer (score 2):

`DLookup` function arguments must all be strings: http://allenbrowne.com/casu-07.html

So for the first two arguments, just enclose them in double-quotes.

For the last argument, the documentation says it's equivalent to a SQL `where` clause, without the word 'where'. Actually since you're returning only a single record from your query you probably don't need the last argument at all:

```
=DLookup("[Level]", "[qryLevel]")
```

Although, I don't see how `qryLevel` can work as an independent query since it refers to `Me` which implies a container object. Better to express as:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Level, myDate
FROM sometable
WHERE custID = [Forms]![MyForm]![customerID]
ORDER BY myDate DESC
```

... which will work in any context--inside or outside a form.

Comment: Thank you. +1 for trying to help.  This is a report summarizing all active customers.  For each customer, there is a row comprised of many fields.  Since the fields are drawn from 6 different tables, I thought the code would be easier to manage in a few queries rather than in 100+ lines of complicated nested SQL.  So Me would refer to the specific row for a given customer, and customerID is the name of a field in each row.  How does this change your answer?

Comment: @CodeMed answer is the same :-) but I will advise you that in the end, it will turn out easier for you if you create a single query that has all the data you need, and bind your report to that instead of doing `DLookup`s to gather data from multiple sources. Also I will say format the query properly. A nicely-formatted SQL query broken up over many lines is immensely easier to parse than one squashed up into a single monstrous line.

Comment: WHERE custID = [Reports]![MyReport]![customerID] implies there is only one customerID for the report.  There are many customerIDs in the report, one for each row of data in the report.  Thus, it needs to refer to the specific row in which it is being called, which is what Me does in my continuous forms.  How do I reference a given row's customerID here?

Comment: Access munges up SQL code, so there is no way to retain any nice formatting of SQL within the Access interface.  Also, I am not a SQL expert, and no one else who will work on this database is a SQL expert, so keeping code in distinct modules will make it maintainable.  The container for customerID is a row in the query that defines the first few fields of each row in the report.  Perhaps Me is not working here because the calling textbox is not in the same query even if it is in the same row as one of the rows in the query. So what name do we use to refer to the container row?

Comment: @CodeMed I see you are under some constraints. And you also have some misconceptions. First issue: `[Reports]![MyReport]![customerID]` does _not_ imply only one customer ID. It refers to the _current_ customer ID being displayed in the report. Reports and forms in Access have the concept of a _current_ record being displayed. If you're writing code within the context of the report/form, you can use `[Me]![FieldName]` to refer to the current value. But if you want to _always_ refer to that field regardless of context, I recommend the `[Reports]![MyReport]![FieldName]` notation.

Comment: As to SQL code, I won't force it on you; but if you do decide to go with more SQL (as I do) what works for me is storing the queries in plain text files outside Access, nicely formatted, then using VBA to (re-)create all the queries in Access. See my answer for this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19149169/20371