# Simple update query in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
UPDATE _DATA SET 
[_DATA].Claim_Status = "UNKNOWN", 
[_DATA].State_Filed = "XX", 
[_DATA].Disease_Category = "UNKNOWN"
WHERE 
((([_DATA].Claim_Status) Is Null) AND 
(([_DATA].State_Filed) Is Null) AND 
(([_DATA].Disease_Category) Is Null));
```

This code is what I got from typing in criteria in query design.
It seems that this only runs when claim_status, state_filed, and disease_category are all null (empty) cells. I want to run a query that fills in "UNKNOWN" into empty cells under Claim_Status, "XX" int empty cells under State_Filed, etc. The condition should not include "AND" which means they are basically run separately.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider 3 simple queries --- one for each of the fields you want to update.  Here is the first of them: `UPDATE _DATA SET Claim_Status = "UNKNOWN" WHERE Claim_Status Is Null`

Comment: Does that mean I have to have 3 queries to make this changes?

Answer (score 1):

This query will only update `Claim_Status`, `State_Filed` and `Disease_Category` if all three of those fields are `NULL`. Say, for instance, that the `State_Filed` is `NULL`, but `Disease_Category` and `Claim_Status` have data populated. In this case, your update would not update `State_Filed` because not all three columns are `NULL`. You should use three separate queries to make sure that all `NULL` columns get updated regardless of if the other two are populated:

```
UPDATE _DATA
SET Claim_Status = 'UNKNOWN' 
WHERE Claim_Status IS NULL

UPDATE _DATA
SET State_Filed = 'XX' 
WHERE State_Filed IS NULL

UPDATE _DATA
SET Disease_Category = 'UNKNOWN' 
WHERE Disease_Category IS NULL
```

Also, I would personally not update `NULL` fields to contain data. If you don't have data for these columns, you don't have the data. If, for instance, you want a `NULL` state to show as `XX` instead of `NULL`, the place to do this is in your presentation layer or reports that you write off this data, not the database itself.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is it possible to use that chunk of lines in one update query so that it does all at once?

Comment: I don't believe so, each `UPDATE` is a separate transaction and must be run by itself. See this for a lengthy workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838593/how-do-i-execute-multiple-sql-statements-in-access-query-editor. Now you could potentially use a case statement to update the value to your default if it is `NULL` or to set it back to itself if it is not, but that would touch every single column of every single row in the DB. I really would not recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nz:

```
UPDATE 
    _DATA 
SET 
    Claim_Status = Nz(Claim_Status, "UNKNOWN"), 
    State_Filed = Nz(State_Filed, "XX"), 
    Disease_Category = Nz(Disease_Category, "UNKNOWN")
WHERE 
    Claim_Status Is Null 
    OR 
    State_Filed Is Null 
    OR 
    Disease_Category Is Null;
```

Comment: Does this change the value only when status,state,and disease are all NULL?

Comment: Then you would use AND, not OR.