# Access SQL - Insert multiple rows wont work

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
INSERT INTO EMP_1 (EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE)
VALUES ('101', 'News', 'John', 'G', '08-Nov-00', '502'),
('102', 'Senior', 'David', 'H', '12-Jul-89', '501');
```

I've been searching for quite some time and most people say to but the comma between the two sets but when I do that it says that it is missing a `;` at the end of the SQL statement so then I separate them with the `;` and get the error that talks about code after the semi-colon, which is understandable.

I've even tried `SELECT` and `UNIONALL` to no avail and was just checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62504/is-there-any-way-to-create-multiple-insert-statements-in-a-ms-access-query) but it still recommended the `SELECT` and `UNIONALL`. Is there something I'm missing completely?

I'm using MS Access 2016, thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  If it's going to be executed from somewhere (which it has to be), why not just execute multiple statements?

Comment: Multiple statements as in different queries or having two sets of code in the same query? Because I've tried doing that but it doesn't allow the second block of code. **Also** it must be in one query.

Comment: Maybe this will help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838593/how-do-i-execute-multiple-sql-statements-in-access-query-editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you have given already state that you CANNOT do

```
insert into foo (c1, c2, c3)
values ("v1a", "v2a", "v3a"),
       ("v1b", "v2b", "v3b"),
       ("v1c", "v2c", "v3c")
```

Which is exactly the way you are doing it now.

Try

```
INSERT INTO EMP_1 (EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE)
    SELECT *
    FROM (select top 1 "101" AS EMP_NUM, "News" AS EMP_LNAME, "John" AS EMP_FNAME, "G" AS EMP_INITIAL, "08-Nov-00" AS EMP_HIREDATE, "502" AS JOB_CODE from onerow
    union all
    select top 1 "102" AS EMP_NUM, "Senior" AS EMP_LNAME, "David" AS EMP_FNAME, "H" AS EMP_INITIAL, "12-Jul-89" AS EMP_HIREDATE, "501" AS JOB_CODE from onerow)
```

I am not sure about MS-Access SQLs. But `"` is differ from `'` in SQL. It seems that the link you give uses `"` as the answer. Why not give it a try? But generally `'` should be used for string values.

Comment: This works, thank you so much even though I don't fully understand the `select top 1`. I changed the `onerow` to the table it is linked to (foreign key) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: The TOP 1 is just used for limiting the result to the First one. I'm glad that it helps :)

Comment: select top 1 "101" AS EMP_NUM, "News" AS EMP_LNAME, "John" AS EMP_FNAME, "G" AS EMP_INITIAL, "08-Nov-00" AS EMP_HIREDATE, "502" AS JOB_CODE from foo return Empty when the table is empty, not work.

Answer (score 2):

MS Access does not permit multiple rows being inserted with a single `insert . . . values`.  I think the "typical" MS Access solution is:

```
INSERT INTO EMP_1 (EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE)
    VALUES ('101', 'News', 'John', 'G', '08-Nov-00', '502');
INSERT INTO EMP_1 (EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE)
    VALUES ('102', 'Senior', 'David', 'H', '12-Jul-89', '501');
```

Comment: This does not work in MS Access because after the first `;` it says `Characters found after end of SQL statement.`

Comment: @Josh . . . You have to execute this as two statements.