# When I run the query , it asks me a parameter query for Johnny?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
INSERT INTO Sales
VALUES (20, Johnny, 4000, 25/10/2018);
```

Also in Query Design it doesn't allow me to make this query:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    custID int,
    custName varchar(255),
    salesValue varchar(255),
    dateSales varchar(255)
    );

INSERT INTO Sales
VALUES (20, Johnny, 4000, 25/10/2018);
```

I want to create a query to make table and input these data inside it simultaneously.

Comment: Please don't ask double-barreled questions. Either ask about the parameter prompt, or about creating a table and inserting data into it simultaneously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute multiple SQL Statements in Access' Query Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838593/how-do-i-execute-multiple-sql-statements-in-access-query-editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use quotation marks  ( ' ): 'johnny'. 
Otherwise access thinks it is a variable you're passing

Comment: This helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax in Access SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO Sales
VALUES (20, 'Johnny', 4000, #25/10/2018#);
```

> I want to create a query to make table and input these data inside it
>   simultaneously.

That Access SQL can't do. You must run two queries to do that.

Comment: You are welcome! If that was the answer, pleaser mark as answered (to the left of the answer box).

Comment: Wouter's answer was part of the answer too. :)